how to use result set of db.all in db.run command that is just next to it. Given these both are in db.serialize()

db.serialize(()=>{

const rightjoinpromise=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

            db.all(
              'select temp_data.colour,temp_data.size,temp_data.price,temp_data.quantity,temp_data.barcode,shoe.shoe_id from shoe right join temp_data on shoe.article_name=temp_data.article_name',
              (err, rows) => {
              console.log('in db.all at start')
              
              if (err) {
                dialog.showMessageBox(mainWindow, {
                  message: `or or here Internal Server Error, ${err.message}`,
                  buttons: []
                })
                reject(err)
              } else {
                console.log('in db.all else at start')
                
                if (!rows.length) {
                  console.log('No result got from right join of TEMP_DATA and SHOE tables')
                } else {
                  // new Promise((resolveee, rejecttt) => {
                    // db.serialize(()=>{
                      console.log('in db.all before foreach at start')
                      console.log("rows: ",rows)
                      rightjoinrows=rows
                      console.log('rows array copied into rightjoinrows',rightjoinrows)
                      resolve(rows)
                      
                      //   resolveee()
                      // }).finally(()=>{
                        
                        // })
                      }
                    }
                  }
                )
                
              })

              rightjoinpromise
              .then((rows)=>{

                rows.forEach((row) => {
                  ...........
        })
})


I've tried using promises, callbacks. but nothing is working
The db.close() at end of db.serialize() is getting executed before db.run() and causing error
I want that result set of db.all() be used in db.run()
